# Unit Test for method that waits for asynchronous event

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, events

I want to test functionality inside of a method which waits for an external asynchronous event. Essentially like this:

```cs
private readonly AutoResetEvent resetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

public async Task MyMethod()
{
    await otherComponent.DoSomething();
    otherComponent.Done += OnDone;
    resetEvent.WaitOne(MaxWait);
    otherComponent.Done -= OnDone;
    resetEvent.Reset();
}

private void OnDone(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    resetEvent.Set();
}
```

`otherComponent.DoSomething` will in production trigger some asynchronous operations. After completion, `Done` will be raised. The method must wait until then. For the test, this component will be mocked. The test should ensure, that `DoSomething` was called and of course should finish properly.

My question is how to simulate this sort of behavior.

The only idea I have is to start a task before calling my test Method like below, but this seems rather hack to me as unit tests should not rely on thread scheduling.

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await Task.Dely(250);
    otherComponentMock.RaiseDone
}
MyMethod
//Asserts
```

Comment: Not really your question, but you better subscribe to the event before calling the method that starts the asnyc operation. Otherwise you might miss the event if it is raised very early.

Comment: Are you using a mocking framework like Moq? Then you can just mock the DoSomething method with Moq's Setup method and call RaiseDone in the mocked method.
To verify that the method was called you can use Moq's Verify method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply create a mock that runs the method synchronously:

```
public class MyMockComponent(){
    public bool WasCalled {get; private set;}
    Task DoSomething(){
       WasCalled = true;
       return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Depending on the type of method you might need to use [Task.FromResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromresult?view=net-7.0) or [TaskCompletionSource](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=c%23%20taskcompletionsource). I would try to avoid `Task.Delay` and `Task.Run` whenever possible, since that tend to make the tests less reliable.

You should also be aware asynchronous code is just more difficult to test. Since there can be timing dependencies that are just difficult to cover well in unit tests. It is perfectly possible that some code passes the unit test, but deadlocks in the real world.

Comment: Combined with Klaus Gütters comment to register for the event before calling `DoSomething`, this works handily. 
And, yes I'm very well aware of the challenges of asynchronous code :) It is unavoidable in this case since we need to talk to another system.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you run `MyMethod` without awaiting, then trigger the Done event from your test method as follows:

```cs
var otherComponent = new OtherComponent();
var sut = new MyClass(otherComponent);

// NOTE: we don't await the task here, we just capture it
var task = sut.MyMethod();

// MyMethod will not complete until the event is raised
Assert.False(task.IsCompleted);

// You can wait as long as you like at this point
await Task.Delay(1000);
Assert.False(task.IsCompleted);

// Raise the event then await the task
otherComponent.RaiseDone();
await task;

// Assert that the task ended cleanly
Assert.True(task.IsCompleted);
```